# EntityManager is closed whenever I return like @PersistenceContext protected EntityManager entityManager;

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, wildfly, entitymanager, jta

I get the Entitymanager like;

```
CRUD(){
        @PersistenceContext
        protected EntityManager entityManager;

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
            return entityManager;
        }
}
```

And in my stateless EJB;I use like

```
@TransactionAttribute(TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED)

public void update(Customer entity) {
EntityManager em = crud().getEntityManager();
System.out.println("*****************"+em.isOpen());

Customer item = em.find(Customer.class,entity.getId());
if (entity.getParentId()!=null) {
    item.setParent(em.find(CRMEntity.class , entity.getParentId()));
item.setParentId(entity.getParentId());
}
```

Here I always get entitymanager is ***closed***. (My print always shows as **false**) Why?

I use wildfly 10, JTA with Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

I was mistakenly closing the session . That caused the issue.

```
if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                session.close();

            }
        }
```